# How to use system lock screen for my app

Tags: android, security, locking

I need to provide some kind of security in my app.
So I believe there are must be some (intent??) way to call

```
startActivityForResult()
```

for system activity with different possible types of locks.
So I want to call system activity for creating password for my app.

So is there are some way to do it?

I am not interested in third-party libraries!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?